# AWS CloudFormation: Creating Security Group fails while it is referencing another security

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am deploying an AWS CloudFormation template. In my template, I am referencing another security group from one security group. But the deployment is failing.

This is my template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Simple 3 tier web application template"
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Default: 'MyanEat'
    Type: String
  VpcCidr:
    Default: '10.1.0.0/16'
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
  InstanceType:
    Default: 't2.micro'
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
Mappings:
  AWSInstanceType2Arch:
    t1.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.nano:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.10xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    g2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    g2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    r3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hi1.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hs1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cr1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cc2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
  AWSRegionArch2AMI:
    us-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
      HVMG2: ami-0a584ac55a7631c0c
    us-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-a0cfeed8
      HVMG2: ami-0e09505bc235aa82d
    us-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-0bdb828fd58c52235
      HVMG2: ami-066ee5fd4a9ef77f1
    eu-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-047bb4163c506cd98
      HVMG2: ami-0a7c483d527806435
    eu-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-f976839e
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-west-3:
      HVM64: ami-0ebc281c20e89ba4b
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0233214e13e500f77
      HVMG2: ami-06223d46a6d0661c7
    ap-northeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-06cd52961ce9f0d85
      HVMG2: ami-053cdd503598e4a9d
    ap-northeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-0a10b2721688ce9d2
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-northeast-3:
      HVM64: ami-0d98120a9fb693f07
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-southeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-08569b978cc4dfa10
      HVMG2: ami-0be9df32ae9f92309
    ap-southeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-09b42976632b27e9b
      HVMG2: ami-0a9ce9fecc3d1daf8
    ap-south-1:
      HVM64: ami-0912f71e06545ad88
      HVMG2: ami-097b15e89dbdcfcf4
    us-east-2:
      HVM64: ami-0b59bfac6be064b78
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ca-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0b18956f
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    sa-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-07b14488da8ea02a0
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-north-1:
      HVM64: ami-0a4eaf6c4454eda75
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-northwest-1:
      HVM64: ami-6b6a7d09
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
Resources:
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidr
      EnableDnsHostnames: True
      EnableDnsSupport: True
  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 0, !Cidr [ !Ref VpcCidr, 12, 8 ] ]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: True
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
  DatabaseSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      CidrBlock: !Select [ 2, !Cidr [ !Ref VpcCidr, 12, 8 ] ]
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
  WebServerInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      ImageId:
        Fn::FindInMap:
          - AWSRegionArch2AMI
          - Ref: AWS::Region
          - Fn::FindInMap:
              - AWSInstanceType2Arch
              - Ref: InstanceType
              - Arch
      AvailabilityZone: !Select
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: !Ref "AWS::Region"
  WebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:
            Ref: SSHLocation
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable TCP connection on port 3306 for database connection
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '0'
          ToPort: '3306'
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            Ref: WebServerSecurityGroup
```

When I deployed the template it was failing. When I print out the event logs. It is saying that creating DBSecurityGroup is failing. What is wrong with my template and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **launched** your template in my sandbox environment (`us-east-1`) in an attempt to identify all issues.

Your template has only **one issue** preventing it from deployment. Namely in your `DBSecurityGroup` you should have:

```
SourceSecurityGroupId: 
 !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Fixing that, resulted in **successful deployment**.

Answer (score 4):

The Last line in your template should be

`SourceSecurityGroupId: !GetAtt WebServerSecurityGroup.GroupId` .

Also i noted inside both `AWS::EC2::Subnet`  the `CidrBlock` property should be

`CidrBlock: !Select [ 0, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 12, 8 ] ]`

and

`CidrBlock: !Select [ 2, !Cidr [ !GetAtt Vpc.CidrBlock, 12, 8 ] ]`